# what's the "dot" command in Linux bash

Tags: bash

I am wondering if there is a difference between:

```
. script.sh
```

and

```
source script.sh
```

Is it the same thing ?

What's the name of the first syntax ? Is it "dot" command ?

Thanks

Comment: They're the same.

Comment: See: `help .` and `help source`

Comment: The POSIX specification does indeed refer to the command as [`dot`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot).